# PHP XML string parsing returns "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Im trying to export some data from [here](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Get&RID=VY1DT6CN014&FORMAT_TYPE=XML) (XML)

e.g  and 
For example i'm trying to get the  by using this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$results = $xml->Iteration[0]->{'Iteration_query-def'};
```

The thing is that returns the Notice written in post's title.

Am i loosing something in the path of XML file ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `simplexml_load_file()` to fetch data from url

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Get&RID=VY1DT6CN014&FORMAT_TYPE=XML');
echo $results = (string)$xml->BlastOutput_iterations->Iteration[0]->{'Iteration_query-def'};
```

Answer (score 1):

Please notice structure of XML document. There is a parent for Iteration called 'BlastOutput_iterations'. Please try below script.

```
$results = $xml->BlastOutput_iterations->Iteration[0]->{'Iteration_query-def'};
```